# How to display file while still in find-file-hook

Tags: emacs

Currently, I use `find-file-hook` to invoke a lengthy compilation/checking of that file.  I have therefore to wait for some time to actually see the file.  What I would like to do instead is to be able to view (not edit) the file already while the checker is running, thus creating the illusion of instantaneous compilation.  How can I do this?

Comment: You could make the buffer read-only, and set a timer to trigger the expensive task (which, once completed, would make the buffer editable).

Answer (score 3):

Using `find-file-hook` means your code will run on every file you open; are you
sure you want this? It may make more sense to create a new major or minor mode
for the type of file you want to run your validation on and then use the
corresponding mode hook. For instance, if you wanted to check all .chk files
(with your new major mode inheriting from `prog-mode`):

```
(define-derived-mode check-mode prog-mode "Checker")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.chk\\'" . check-mode))
(add-hook 'check-mode-hook 'check-mode-computation-hook)
```

As for the actual hook, this code (going off phils' comment) works for me:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun slow-computation ()
  (dotimes (i 10000000)
    (+ i 1)))

(defun check-mode-computation-hook ()
  (let ((cb (current-buffer))
        (ro buffer-read-only))
    (setq-local buffer-read-only t)
    (run-at-time .1 nil
                 (lambda ()
                   (with-current-buffer cb
                     (message "Loading...")
                     (slow-computation)
                     (setq-local buffer-read-only ro)
                     (message "Loaded!"))))))
```

Note, though, that though this will display the file, emacs will still be frozen
until it finishes its processing, as
emacs [doesn't actually support multithreading](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoThreading). To get around this, you may
have to use a library like [async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async), [deferred](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred), or [concurrent](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred/blob/master/README-concurrent.markdown).

Answer (score 1):

You should considered using [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) which provides async syntax checking for most programming languages  and provides a nice API for implementing new/custom *checkers*.

Comment: My question was not about incrementality.